Problema with bootstrapDualListbox and ajax
I have the following:
html:
<div id="modal-form" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" style="z-index: 0;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content" style="margin-left: -20%; margin-right: -20%;">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <!-- true -->
          <div class="ibox-content">
            <% path = if params[:action] == 'edit'
                (edit_client_company_egress_path(@client, @company, @egress))
              else
                new_client_company_egress_path(@client, @company) 
              end
            %>
            <%= 
              form_tag(
                path, method: :get, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }
              ) do
            %>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h3 class="text-center">Buscar Documentos</h3>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= label :document_bring_ruc, "RUT Proveedor o RUT Trabajador", class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
                  <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <%= text_field_tag :ruc, nil, class: "form-control document-bring-ruc" %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= label :document_date_since, 'Fecha de Documento Desde', class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%=
                      text_field_tag :document_date_since, nil,
                      value: Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),
                      class: 'form-control datepicker-report readonly-input',
                      id: 'document-date-since',
                      readonly: true
                    %>
                  </div>
                  <%= label :document_date_until, 'Fecha de Documento Hasta', class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%=
                      text_field_tag :document_date_until, nil,
                      value: Date.today.at_end_of_month.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),
                      class: 'form-control datepicker-report readonly-input',
                      id: 'document-date-until',
                      readonly: true
                    %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= label :due_date_since, 'Fecha de Vencimiento Desde', class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%=
                      text_field_tag :duet_date_since, nil,
                      placeholder: Date.today.at_beginning_of_month.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),
                      class: 'form-control datepicker-report due-date-since readonly-input',
                      readonly: true
                    %>
                  </div>
                  <%= label :due_date_until, 'Fecha de Vencimiento Hasta', class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%=
                      text_field_tag :due_date_until, nil,
                      placeholder: Date.today.at_end_of_month.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'),
                      class: 'form-control datepicker-report due-date-until readonly-input',
                      readonly: true
                    %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= label :payment_date_since, 'Semana de Pago Desde', class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%= select_tag :payment_date_since,
                                    options_for_select([]),
                                    class: 'form-control payment-since',
                                    style: 'width: 100%'
                    %>
                  </div>
                  <%= label :payment_date_until, 'Semana de Pago Hasta', class: 'col-lg-2 control-label' %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%= select_tag :payment_date_until,
                                    options_for_select([]),
                                    class: 'form-control payment-until',
                                    style: 'width: 100%'
                    %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= label :bring_document_money, "Moneda", class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%=
                      select_tag :bring_document_money,
                      options_for_select(
                        Invoice.money.map { |money, code| [money, code] }
                      ), class: "form-control bring-document-money"
                    %>
                  </div>
                  <%= label :bring_document_type, "Tipo Documento", class: "col-lg-2 control-label" %>
                  <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <%=
                      select_tag :bring_document_type,
                      options_for_select(
                        Invoice.document_types.map { |dt, code| [dt, code] }
                      ),
                      class: "form-control bring-document-type",
                      multiple: true,
                      style: 'width: 100%'
                    %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <%= label :documents, "Documentos", class: "col-lg-12 control-label" %>
                  <div class="col-lg-12" style="margin: 0 0 10px 0;">
                    <%= select_tag(
                      :documents,
                      options_for_select([]),
                      multiple: true,
                      class: "form-control dual_select documents-selected",
                    ) %>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :invoices, nil, id: 'modalInvoices' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :renditions, nil, id: 'modalRenditions' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :tax_forms, nil, id: 'modalTaxForms' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :name, nil, id: 'modalName' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :authorizer, nil, id: 'modalAuthorizer' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :document_date, nil, id: 'modalDocumentDate' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :posting_date, nil, id: 'modalPostingDate' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :money, nil, id: 'modalMoney' %>
                <%= 
                  hidden_field_tag :company_account_id,
                  nil, id: 'modalCompanyAccount'
                %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :exchange_type, nil, id: 'modalExchangeType' %>
                <%= hidden_field_tag :transfer_number, nil, id: 'modalTransferNumber' %>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p class="text-center">
                  <%= submit_tag 'Seleccionar', class:"btn btn-block btn-primary"%>
                </p>
              </div>
            <% end %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

js
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
  if ($('body').attr('data-resource') == 'incomes') {
    $(IncomeForm.setup);
  }
});
var IncomeForm = {
    bringDocuments: function(){
    var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split('/')
    var client = pathArray[2]
    var company = pathArray[4]
    var ruc =  $('.document-bring-ruc').val()
    var document_date_since = $('#document-date-since').val()
    var document_date_until = $('#document-date-until').val()
    var due_date_since = $('.due-date-since').val()
    var due_date_until = $('.due-date-until').val()
    var payment_since = $('.payment-since').val()
    var payment_until = $('.payment-until').val()
    var bring_document_money = $('.bring-document-money').val()
    var bring_document_type = $('.bring-document-type').val()

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: '/clients/'+ client +'/companies/'+ company + '/api/sell_invoices/income_required',
      data: {
        ruc: ruc,
        document_date_since: document_date_since,
        document_date_until: document_date_until,
        due_date_since: due_date_since,
        due_date_until: due_date_until,
        payment_since: payment_since,
        payment_until: payment_until,
        bring_document_money: bring_document_money,
        bring_document_type: bring_document_type
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var nonSelected = $('#bootstrap-duallistbox-nonselected-list_documents\\[\\]')
        var selectedSelect = $('#bootstrap-duallistbox-selected-list_documents\\[\\]')

        var documentsSelect = $('.documents-selected')
        nonSelected.empty()

        if (data.sell_invoices) {
          data.sell_invoices.forEach(function(item) {
            var text = item.correlative + " - " + item.rut + " - " + item.document_type + " - " + item.money
            var option = '<option value="' + item.id + '" data-type="invoice">' + text + '</option>'
            nonSelected.append(option)
          })

          nonSelected.bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true)
        }
        
        selectedSelect.bootstrapDualListbox('refresh', true)
      }
    })
  },

  setup: function () {
    $('.dual_select').bootstrapDualListbox({
      selectorMinimalHeight: 160
    })

    $('.payment-since, .payment-until, .bring-document-type').select2()

    $('#bring-documents').on('click', function() {
      IncomeForm.bringDocuments()
    })

    $('#document-date-since, #document-date-until, .due-date-since, ' +
      '.due-date-until, .payment-since, .payment-until, ' +
      '.bring-document-money, .bring-document-type, .document-bring-ruc').on('change input', function() {
      if (!updatingOptions) {
        IncomeForm.bringDocuments()
      }
    })
  }
}


As you can see I have a form, which is in a modal, which is for selecting documents, which we can manage by varying the different filters, the problem I have is the following, when I select some element from the duallistbox and then make any changes to the filters, both box1 and box2 are emptied, the nonselected and the selected ones, I need them to remain, only box1 is updated, when trying the way I show, box1 is never filled, if I remove this: selectedSelect.bootstrapDualListbox( 'refresh', true)
It brings me information, but when I select it everything disappears, I don't know what could happen or what the solution could be, does anyone know?
